# What does keywords in my /etc/network/interfaces means?

Tags: networking

My etc/network/interfaces file contain :

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

What is the meaning of auto, iface, inet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The different keywords have the following meaning:

**auto: the interface should be configured during boot time.**

**iface : interface**

**inet: interface uses TCP/IP networking.**

That means interface **eth0** should be configured during boot time ,  and interface name **eth0**

uses TCP/IP protocol and can be configured by Dhcp .